# Add new States In Dropdown Of Address in ORO Commerce

Tags: orocommerce

I have installed orocommerce 4.1 and I want to add new values in States dropdown in Orocommerce how to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

In OroCommerce, the state is represented by the [Region](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/4.1.4/src/Oro/Bundle/AddressBundle/Entity/Region.php#L32) entity.

You can add new states with the [data migration](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities-data-management/data-fixtures/#fixtures-and-demo-data), like that one:
https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/4.1.4/src/Oro/Bundle/AddressBundle/Migrations/Data/ORM/LoadCountryData.php